# Cant understand why adding javascript is stopping site search results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website im working on that has a number of JS scripts.
I'm trying to add a live ajax search feature and the Javascript is stopping the search feature on my site showing the results.

Can anyone see why the following code would stop the search feature of my site from returning results?

If i remove the last script that starts JQuery(document).ready my search results work as normal.
If i remove the Ajaxlivesearch.js reference it works as normal.
Removing either of these does however stop my Ajax Live Search working.

````
   <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 


  <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxlivesearch.js"></script>


<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mySearch").ajaxlivesearch({
        loaded_at: <?php echo time(); ?>,
        token: <?php echo "'" . $handler->getToken() . "'"; ?>,
        max_input: <?php echo Config::getConfig('maxInputLength'); ?>,
        onResultClick: function(e, data) {
            // get the index 0 (first column) value
            var selectedOne = jQuery(data.selected).find('td').eq('0').text();

            // set the input value
            jQuery('#ls_query').val(selectedOne);

            // hide the result
            jQuery("#ls_query").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:hide_result');
        },
        onResultEnter: function(e, data) {
            // do whatever you want
            // jQuery("#ls_query").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:search', {query: 'test'});
        },
        onAjaxComplete: function(e, data) {

        }
    });
})
</script>```
````

Comment: `.eq('0')` is a code smell.  The input to eq is expected to be a Number, not a String

Comment: What's in `ajaxlivesearch.js`?  If there's errors or overwriting of $ etc it could easily stop your site working.  "*If i remove the Ajaxlivesearch.js reference it works as norma*" - do you not get a console error that `.ajaxlivesearch` is not a function?

Comment: ajaxlivesearch can be viewed at the following url. its slightly too big to post here https://github.com/iranianpep/ajax-live-search/blob/master/js/ajaxlivesearch.js